# retina display - fitting large background image in css into smaller dimensions

Tags: html, css, retina-display

I have the following css for my toolbar which displays social icons:

```
.toolbar ul li {
    height: 102px;
    width: 102px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/social_icons.png) center top no-repeat;
}
.toolbar ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.toolbar ul li.facebook {
    background-position: 0 0px;
}
.toolbar ul li.facebook:hover {
    background-position: -102px 0px;
}
.toolbar ul li.twitter {
    background-position: 0 -102px;
}
.toolbar ul li.twitter:hover {
    background-position: -102px -102px;
}
```

However, I want my icon to be only 34px x 34px when rendered in HTML. The reason for the higher resolution image is so that I can display it better on retina screens. However, it doesn't seem to work when I change to:

```
.toolbar ul li {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/social_icons.png) center top no-repeat;
}
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use display `inline-block` instead of display block

Or:

```
background-size: 43px 43px;
```